# how to use powershell object properties directly without typecasting and spliting?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, scripting

I have created a small script to transfer value of Active directory pc attribute called pssfulllocation from one pc to anoter pc..

To achieve this I have to use typecasting + splitting..

Here is the script which works

```
$oldpc=read-host "Enter old pc name"
$newpc=read-host "Enter new pc name"
$my=Get-ADComputer -Identity $oldpc -Properties * | select pssfulllocation 

  $itemcast=[string]$my
  $b = $itemcast.Split("=")[1]    
  $c=$b.Split("}")[0]

Set-ADComputer -identity $newpc -Replace @{pSSFullLocation="$c"}
```

and the output will **nicely do the intended job**.. in this manner.. and this is the **desired result**..

[image]

But if i don't use typecasting + splitting as per the below script--

```
$oldpc=read-host "Enter old pc name"
$newpc=read-host "Enter new pc name"
$my=Get-ADComputer -Identity $oldpc -Properties * | select pssfulllocation 
Set-ADComputer -identity $newpc -Replace @{pSSFullLocation="$my"}
```

the out put is below.. which is **not what i** want..

[image]

In a nutshell if i don't use typecasting + splitting output will be added as @{pSSFullLocation=C/BRU/B/0/ADM/1 but it should only be added as C/BRU/B/0/ADM/1 as per this:

[image]

I feel typecasting + splitting should be a workaround and not the proper method.. Any other powershell way to achieve this without using typecasting + splitting ?

Comment: Have you checked what `Get-ADComputer -Identity $oldpc -Properties pSSFullLocation | Get-Member` returns? Perhaps you want something like `(Get-ADComputer -Identity $oldpc -Properties pSSFullLocation).somethingreturnedbyget-member`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
$my=Get-ADComputer -Identity $oldpc -Properties * | select pssfulllocation
```

You don't `Select-Object` to access an attribute's value. Note the `-Object`, not `-Attribute`, in the cmdlet name. Instead, collect the object returned by `Get-AdComputer` then use the attribute directly.

```
$my = Get-ADComputer -Identity $oldpc -Properties *
$psfl = $my.pSSFullLocation
Set-ADComputer -identity $newpc -Replace @{pSSFullLocation="$psfl"}
```

Comment: You rockstar!! It worked... I feel im learning fast.. faster. Really appreciate your kind help..

Answer (score 1):

Or even this could do the job **"-expandproperty"**

```
$oldpc=read-host "Enter old pc name"
$newpc=read-host "Enter new pc name"

$my=Get-ADComputer -Identity $oldpc -Properties * | select -expandproperty pssfulllocation 

Set-ADComputer -identity $newpc -Replace @{pSSFullLocation="$my"}
```